# Facing issue while configuring EC2 WAF ACL

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-waf

I am having a free tier AWS account, I am adding WAF with my LB(load balancer) having one instance on EC2. Currently, the security group has only HTTP 80 port.

My instance is located on the Asia Pacific (Mumbai) region and when I am creating RULE OR Condition for ACL, I am not getting this region there.

So I have tried to make ACL with the different region and without any rule just configure with the load balancer, After creating ACL when I go for Associate the load balancer with ACL, So there is no load balancer shown in the drop down like below:

[image]

please help me, Where can be mistake done by me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS WAF is not supported yet in the Mumbia region, so if your instance and load balancer is in Mumbai you won't be able to use WAF directly:
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regional-product-services/

You also can't put your WAF in a different region and connect it to your ALB, that won't work either as you have seen.

The only other option is for you to make use of a Cloudfront distribution in front of your load balancer, and your WAF is then linked to your Cloudfront distribution.